Get the primary key of a relation in Micronaut Data
I am trying to use Micronaut Data with the micronaut-jdbc-hikari driver (JDBC essentially). I am using the 4.5.0 platform BOM.
My problem is defined as following:

I have two entities, one has a ManyToOne relation to the other
I want to retrieve a projection of that entity, and some information about the relation

Now I know that apparently nested projections are not possible in Micronaut Data. That's acceptable for me. It would suffice fully to get the key of the relation (hence the primary key of the relationship). To my understanding, it should be possible to simply select this as a regular member of the table. However, I have tried many different methods to no avail.
Let me expand with some code. First, my transaction class.
@MappedEntity
public record Transaction(
    @NonNull @NotNull @NotBlank @Id String id,
    @NonNull @NotNull @NotBlank LocalDate madeOn,
    @NonNull @NotNull @NotBlank @Size(max = 3) String currencyCode,
    @NotNull @NonNull @NotBlank String category,
    @NotNull @NonNull @NotBlank Boolean duplicated,
    @NotNull @NonNull @NotBlank LocalDateTime createdAt,
    @NotNull @NonNull @NotBlank LocalDateTime updatedAt,
    @Nullable @Relation(value = Kind.MANY_TO_ONE) Account account
) {

}

The transaction class has a ManyToOne relationship with Account:
@MappedEntity
public record Account(
    @NonNull @NotNull @NotBlank @Id String id,
    @NonNull @NotNull @NotBlank String name,
    @NonNull @NotNull @NotBlank @Size(max = 3) String currencyCode,
    @NonNull @NotNull @NotBlank LocalDateTime createdAt,
    @NonNull @NotNull @NotBlank LocalDateTime updatedAt
) {

}

I would like to project my transactions to
@Introspected
@Serdeable
public record TransactionDTO(
    String id,
    String mode,
    LocalDate madeOn,
    String accountId  // this one will not work
) {

}

And a simple repository to implement the functionality:
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
public interface TransactionRepository extends PageableRepository<Transaction, String> {

  Page<TransactionDTO> listByAccountInListAndMadeOnBetweenOrderByMadeOnDesc(
      List<Account> accounts, LocalDate from, LocalDate to, Pageable pageable
  );
}

This example will not compile, as accountId is an invalid field. What would be the correct approach to implement this with Micronaut Data?

Eventually I solved this by using a JOIN and simply writing a method that maps the entities to my DTO itself.
